# Stop a recursive loop into the method

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Is possible stop a loop into a method call by selector?
I have created a new method for stop all running process, but I don't know how stop while loop in the audioloop method.

This is my code, please see:

```
-(id) init{
    if((self=[super init]) ) { 
       // @property int isLoop;
       self.isLoop = 1;
       audioThread = [NSThread new];
       [audioThread initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(audioLoop) object:nil];
       [audioThread setThreadPriority:1];
       [audioThread start];   
    }
}

// in this method i would stop while loop of audioLoop method
-(void)stopAllRunning{
    self.isLoop = 0;
    [audioThread cancel];
}

 -(void) audioLoop{
    while (isLoop) {
        [_midiClock update];
    }
 }
```

Comment: Replace the `while (true)` with a check against a property of your object. Something like `while (self.playAudio)`, and when you want to stop it, do `audioObj.playAudio = false;`

Comment: I, i have update my code. Now is right?

Comment: You tell me, you're the one who can test it. (That said, you shouldn't really edit your question to add the solution in it, it makes it confusing for people who want to provide full answers.)

Comment: FYI - There is no recursion in your loop. It's just a simple loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `condition` and a `break` statement for doing this:

```
while (true)
{
     if(yourCondition)
        break;
     else
        [_midiClock update];
}
```

or Simply:

```
while (yourCondition)
{
   [_midiClock update];
}
```

Comment: How can pass a condition to method?

Comment: @Jimmy: from where did you calling the `stopAllRunning` method ?